# running systemctl via ssh without asking for password

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, sudo, systemctl

I want to run ssh without asking for a password and invoke systemctl without a password I tried doing the following:

```
ssh -t <user>@<host> "echo <password> | sudo -S systemctl status kubelet"
```

and:

```
sshpass -p '$<password>' ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' <user>@<host> 'sudo service kubelet restart
```

also:

```
echo <password> | ssh -tt <user>@<host> "sudo service kubelet restart"
```

and:

```
sshpass -p '$<password>' ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' <user>@<host> "echo <password> | sudo -S service kubelet restart"
```

i added the user to the sudoers and i am able to run systemctl without password all the commands from above ask for a password except:

```
sshpass -p '$<password>' ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' <user>@<host> 'sudo service kubelet restart
```

which gives me no prompt and looks like it worked but did nothing.

checked the history to see if anything was done on the remote system and it hasn't.

edit:
I want to do it without copying keys from one system to another and do ssh without password -

Comment: Can you try to connect to the remote host and execute the command manually then put here what you get in order to understand well the issue.

Comment: In your last one, you're missing an ending apostrophe. Also, try adding `-v` for verbosity wherever you can.

Comment: the missing apostrophe at the end is a miss when i copied the line. 
i did connect to the remote host and the command ran on the remote host without a problem, that's not the issue, the issue is that there has to be a simple and easy way to parse the password to the command.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". If one of the answers solved your issue, consider accepting it. If you have a solution different from all answers, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1416433/158442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

I used python3 for this solution, and tho not elegant but it works(this is not the full script but only the relevant part).

```py
initiate_restart = [
    "echo <password> | sudo -S systemctl restart kubelet",
    "echo <password> | sudo -S systemctl restart docker",
]
node = paramiko.SSHClient()
print(node)
node.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    node.connect(hostname=get_ip, username=user_name, password=node_pass)
    with open("/tmp/reset_log.log", "a") as f:
        f.write(date + ' Restarting ' + 'Node-' + get_ip + "\n")
except:
    print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
    with open("/tmp/reset_log.log", "a") as f:
        f.write(date + ' Could not connect to' + ' Node-' + get_ip + "\n")
    exit()
for command in initiate_restart:
    print("="*50, command, "="*50)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = node.exec_command(command)
    print(stdout.read().decode())
    err = stderr.read().decode()
    if err:
        print(err)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the host run and save the file at the default location.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then copy ID.

```
ssh-copy-id root@<host>
```

Then simply run your command.

```
ssh root@<host> systemctl status kubelet
```

Comment: I know i can do it, and it works, i don't want to copy a key to the remote system.

Comment: What's the problem? This is the *most correct and secure* way to use SSH. The public key that you copy could be made entirely public (e.g. published on the web site and so on), there is nothing secret with it and no security problems. It couldn't be used alone for authentication. It is private key is what you should keep in secret, and you truly shouldn't copy it anywhere onto remote system.

Comment: There should not be a reason, this is the way I need to do it. 
if you want to know, my client asked me not to do it this way, I'm not going to argue.
anyway, I figured it out, not with bash but with python. 
I used paramiko for this, see my answer above.

Comment: What to say. Educate your clients.